# Running remote scripts in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-remoting

I've successfully got winrm working and I'm able to run `Enter-PSSession my-machine` in the shell and subsequently enter commands. However, when I try to run a script that starts up a remote session, all subsequent calls are run on the local machine. For instance:

```
PS> test.ps1
```

Contents of test.ps1

```
Enter-PSSession remote-pcname
gc env:computername
```

prints out `local-pcname` instead of `remote-pcname` any idea why the script file is not honoring the remote session? It is definitely successfully connecting because when the script finishes I'm returned to the shell prompt of the remote machine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is: Enter-PSSession is intended for interactive use.  If you want to execute commands on a remote system from a script, use invoke-command.

A similiar thread on the Technet forums is here:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverpowershell/thread/90e92d4e-716b-4b4d-956f-d38645e5c035

Comment: +1 you answer before, but as it was written I post it even though

Answer (score 4):

For me it work as documented. `Enter-PSSession` start an **interactive** session, it's for interactive use.

So to execute a script you can use `New-PSSession` to create a session and Invoke-Command using the remote session you created with New-PSSession.