# Powershell error when trying to enter psssession

Tags: powershell

I am trying to enter a new PSSession. If I manually run each line it works, but when I run it as part of a script, I get an error. The creds are valid and it seems the session is created, I just cant enter it in the script. The line number referenced is the write-host. Even if I just have an assignment to a variable it errors there.

```
$cred = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $pw)
New-PSSession -ComputerName App02 -Credential $cred
Get-PSSession | Enter-PSSession

Write-Host "ERROR: Partial Service Deployment. See error log file(s)"
```

I get this as an error:

> Cannot perform operation because operation "NewNotImplementedException
>   at offset 63 in file:line:column :0:0 " is not
>   implemented. At C:\DEV\Sandbox\Sandbox.ps1:29 char:14
>   +              Write-Host "ERROR: Partial Service Deployment. See error log file(s ...
>   +              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotImplemented: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NotImplemented

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `Enter-PSSession` in a script. Reason: It is intended for interactive purpose. You can use `Invoke-Command` with the corresponding `-Session` parameter to perform commands remotely.

See also this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119121/running-remote-scripts-in-powershell).

Example of `Invoke-Command`:

```
$cred = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $pw)
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName App02 -Credential $cred
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock { Get-Service * } #Return all services from the remote machine
```

Answer (score 0):

`Enter-PSSession` can only be used interactively.  For scripting, use `Invoke-Command`, and point it at the computer you want to run the command or scriptblock on.